# Identity about determinant of $I-A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, random-matrices

I was reading the book [Introduction to Random Matrices](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjB98-K1_n9AhVsyjgGHRn_BkwQFnoECA0QAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il%2F%7Ezeitouni%2Fcupbook.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0wbMPwbj788zuq0QFfT4Cp) by Anderson et al and I think that the authors are using the following characterization of $\det(I-A)$ in Lemma $3.2.4$ in the book.

$$\det(I-A)=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\,\sum_{1\leq\nu(1)<...<\nu(k)\leq n}(-1)^{k}\det(a_{\nu(i)\nu(j)})_{i,j=1}^{k}$$

But I have never seen such a characterization and neither can I find any resources on this. I am unable to prove it on my own and it should involve a fair bit of Alternating algebra to prove it So if anyone can help me out by suggesting a reference or by telling me more about this then I'll be grateful. Also please tell me if this is at all true.

Comment: Essentially, when the $i$ in not in the range, $\nu(1),\dots,\nu(k),$ we are taking the $1$ from the $i$th diagonal element. So the set of permutations which fix those $n-k$ $i$ values will contribute $\pm$ the determinant in the sum when we just take the $1$ terms in the product. The sign argument is the messy part.

Comment: So if you write the determinant a $$\sum_{\pi\in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\pi)\prod_i(\delta_{i\pi(i)}-a_{\pi_i})$$ we get all the terms of $(-1)^n\det A,$ plus additional terms $$\sum_{J\subseteq [n]}\,\sum_{\pi\mid \pi j=j\forall j\in J} \operatorname{sgn}(\pi)\prod_{i\notin J} (-a_{i\pi(i)})$$ But the sign of $\pi$ is the same if treated as a permutation on $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$ or restricted to $[n]\setminus J,$ since it is the identity on $J.$

Comment: Essentially, the $J\subseteq [n]$ is the set of indices of diagonals that are contributing $1$ rather than $a_{jj}.$ So the inner sum is $(-1)^{n-|J|}\det(a_{i,j})_{i,j\notin J}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Perfect. I was looking precisely for an intuitive explanation. Unfortunately the question is closed so it is not an answer otherwise I'd have accepted it(and upvoted).